# Selenium Navigator pattern from C# to Java

Tags: c#, java, selenium, automated-tests, testng

I want to call all methods through one navigator object instead of a lot of page objects directly.

*Navigator pattern exists to do some additional things before or after or even instead of passed him methods to Page Objects*.

So, I found how to implement **Navigator pattern in C# (and it uses delegates)**, but my project written in Java and all selenium automation test framework(it uses Selenium, Java and Testng) must be too.

**how can I write the following code (Navigator pattern) in Java?** (there isn't delegates feature in Java).

Navigator interface:

```
public interface INavigator
{
  TT Open<tt>() where TT : PageBase, new();
  TT Navigate<tt>(Action action) where TT : PageBase, new();

  void ClickAndWaitForText(Action action, string text);
 ...
}
}
```

Usage of navigator is something like this:

```
[TestFixture]
 public class LoginTest
  {
      private SeleniumScope _scope;
      private INavigator _navigator;

      [TestFixtureSetUp]
      public void Setup()
      {
          _scope = new SeleniumScope();
          _navigator = new Navigator(_scope.Selenium);
      }
      [Test]
      public void Login()
      {
          var login = _navigator.Open<LoginPage>();
          login.User.SetText("admin");
          login.Password.SetText("god");
          _navigator.Navigate<HomePage>(login.ClickLogin);
      }
```

P.S. As you can see it looks good in C#, but how to write a Navigator pattern in java?

But how to implement Navigator pattern correctly in java?. for example _navigator.Navigate(login.ClickLogin);. _navigator must process (say add waitFor() or something else) before execution of passed method "login.ClickLogin" for the right object "HomePage". Unlike C# Java doesn't have delegates feature.

Answer (score 0):

Designing this has little to do with Selenium, you can apply good Java design practices to this problem. For example, declare an interface that defines one method (runTest) that accepts one parameter (the Selenium object DesiredCapabilities). On each of your Selenium test classes, implement the interface and put your test code there. Now in your "Navigator" class, register the test classes. Your "Navigator" class will iterate through these registered test cases and call `runTest` on them.

Actually, there's an even better way to do it though. Use JUnit and declare each of your Selenium test classes as extends `TestCase` which is a JUnit class. In your navigator class, implement the following code:

```
public static Test tests() {
   //FirstTest, SecondTest, and ThirdTest extend TestCase
   TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
   suite.addTestSuite(FirstTest.class);
   suite.addTestSuite(SecondTest.class);
   suite.addTestSuite(ThirdTest.class);
   return suite;
}
```

Then to run the tests put this in your main method in your Navigator class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    junit.textui.TestRunner.run(tests());
}
```

As an example of what your `FirstTest.class` would look like:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() throws Exception {
   for (DesiredCapabilities capability : SeleniumUtil.getCapabilities()){
      runSeleniumTest(capability);
   }
}
```

The above example does the same thing as your `Navigator` class, except it's simpler and works well as a pattern for any Selenium JUnit tests.

Comment: Note: my answer assumes you know a little about Selenium. If you don't know what a DesiredCapabilities set is, for example, I suggest you start reading the Selenium website help pages.

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not what I need. I use test-runner "Testng". I mean I want to find out how to implement correctly in java the code shown in the main message, for example `_navigator.Navigate<HomePage>(login.ClickLogin);`. _navigator must process (say add waitFor() or something else) before execution of passed method "login.ClickLogin" for the right object "HomePage". But how to do it in Java? because it doesn't have delegates feature(in code above in C# `Action action`).

Comment: @user2962149 I already told you. Use an interface. Have your test classes implement that interface. Register them with the Navigator. The Navigator will then run them. There IS NO delegate functionality in Java 7 or below.